# SnappyFramedInputStream vs SnappyInputStream

Tags: java, snappy

I'd like to know implementation/performance differences between Java `SnappyFramedInputStream` and `SnappyInputStream`, as well as best usage scenarios for each one of them. (Same for their `OutputStream` counterparts).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some info [here](https://code.google.com/p/snappy/source/browse/trunk/framing_format.txt) about the framing format.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The functional difference is that SnappyInputStream is proprietary and SnappyFramedInputStream implements the framing format defined by google (as linked by @andres.santana).

From a performance perspective, I am going to guess that you are talking about the xerial snappy-java implementation (as I believe that is the only SnappyFramedInputStream that currently exists). The difference is that the framing format includes a crc32c checksum on every frame. The SnappyFramedInputStream allows the verification of this checksum to be disabled, which effectively nullifies any difference on a pure reading perspective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your precise and concise response. And yes, I meant the xerial snappy-java implementation. (I'll add the java label to the question).

Comment: @Magnamag, there is a pure java snappy implementation, but it does not (yet) include support for the framing format. That project also has a proprietary streaming format. It's proprietary format is not compatible with xerial's and is actually more similar to the standard definition in that it includes a checksum on each frame.  https://github.com/dain/snappy